# JMenu Bar Transparente JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, jmenubar

tengo un panel y dentro un JMenuBar y quiero poner transparente este mismo, pero me sale con un fondo gris y no puedo cambiarlo. 
Lo puse opaco pero tampoco funciona ni tampoco cambia el fondo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

traté con éste código pero no funciona:

```
UIManager.put("jMGeneral.opaque", false);
jMGeneral.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Quisiera algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Donde tienes:

```
jMGeneral.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Cambialo por esto:

```
jMGeneral.setBackground(new Color(0f,0f,0f,0f));
```

La clase `Color` se utiliza para encapsular colores en el espacio de color RGB predeterminado o colores en espacios de color arbitrarios identificados por un `ColorSpace`.

Cada color tiene un valor alfa implícito de `1.0` o uno explícito proporcionado en el constructor. El valor alfa define la transparencia de un color y puede ser representado por un valor flotante en el rango de `0,0 - 1,0` o `0 - 255`.

Un valor alfa de `1,0` o `255` significa que el color es completamente opaco y un valor alfa de `0` o `0,0` significa que el color es completamente transparente. Cuando se construye un color con un alpha explícito o se obtienen los componentes de color / alfa de un color, los componentes de color nunca se premultiplican por el componente alfa.

Date una vuelta por la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) que esta muy entendible.

Comment: ahora me la pone de color gris, ¿que parámetros son esos que lleva el color?  en esta parte :
`new Color(0f,0f,0f,0f)`

Comment: ¿Entonces son colores en formato RGB?, es que lo que quiero es poner una imagen de fondo en un label, eso ya quedo y quiero dejar superpuesta el JMenu y este hacerlo transparente. pero el JMenu bar se me pone gris con esos colores que me diste

Comment: es el nombre del jMenuBar

Comment: en si solo quiero dejarlo de color blanco, no transparente, solo blanco.

Comment: no funciona, le pongo así:
`jMGeneral.setBackground(Color.WHITE);` y se queda igual, como mi primer foto, pongo los valores que me diste y se queda de color gris. No se que hacer.

Answer (score 0):

```
jMGeneral.setUI(new BasicMenuBarUI(){});
jMGeneral.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

Prueba así.

Comment: Podrías dar una explicación de esto, es para complementar tu pregunta. De esta manera dejará de ser de baja calidad :D